# Manually track WCF client's inactivity time

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I have a `WCF` client that need to close its connection to the server in case no call has been made for more than X seconds.
My server have a long `inactivityTimeout` which I cannot change (the only changes I can make are in the client's side)

After reading I understood that i cannot use `WCF's` configuration in order to do it so I thought of tracking the time between the calls that my `WCF` client is making manually.
In case the client hasn't made a call for more than X seconds I will close that connection.

I thought of 2 ways to implement it but I don't like either of them:

1. Add some code to all my functions that will save the call time.
2. Using `IClientMessageInspector` - in that case I will need to send the time of the call to an external class that will save this data and in time will call the client in case it recognizes that a call to the server haven't been made for a X seconds.

I am looking for a simple solution like an event that will get called on each call to the server so all the logic of the time tracking the disconnection will happen in the same class (the `WCF's` client code) or maybe some way to use `WCF's` configuration so it will automatically close the connection in case of inactivity of more than X seconds.

The binding I am using is `netTcpBinding` with a `reliableSession`

Any ideas on how to implement it ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the session open between calls? Ideally you would close the connection after each call.

Comment: There is a part in the system that i cannot change, This part is also making me save an open session until my client closes the application.
The problem that i have is that i cannot know when did the client closed the application so i am trying to close the connection for him if it has been idle for more than X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much always have a method that returns a reference to an open service client `GetMyService`. That way I have the logic to instantiate and open the service in one spot, mostly so I can switch endpoints between development, test and production environments reliably. In my setup the method that makes the service call closes the service but if you leave that out you get your solution.

Have a method that returns the service client and keeps a reference to it. If the service is closed it would open the service, On the next call to the method it just returns the open service client. Then all you need to do is create a timer that closes the service and reset it each time your `GetService` method is called.

I cannot imagine a scenario where you need to keep the connection open but can close it "willy nilly". Unless maybe you need to pass some state in whenever you open the connection? In which case my solution makes more sense. I still suspect you don't need to keep the connection open. Otherwise randomly closing it because the user went for coffee would break it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i cannot use it in my solution.
The service that i am writing is connecting from one side to a WCF netTcpBinding and form the other side to a REST service.
The purpose of this service is to keep the connection to the netTcpBinding open as long as the REST client is using it.
I want to close the connection to the netTcpBinding in case the REST client did not make a call in X seconds.
I know it is not the "best" architecture but i cannot change it.

Comment: Just FYI your comments are not very useful, you say you cannot use my answer but give no reason, you repeat that you need to keep the connection open, but you don't give a reason. You also seem to use "client" and "service" interchangeably.